# How to hide a column in sql generated table? (php+jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Looked through various solutions but unable to resolve. So far what I have implemented, only the first row is getting hid whereas the id of column remains same throughout. Can you please tell me that what needs to be changed?

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>
$(document).on("pagecreate","#pageone",function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var theID = $(this).attr('id');  
    $("#"+theID).slideToggle("slow");
    $("table, tr,th#"+theID).slideToggle("slow");
    $("table, tr,td#"+theID).slideToggle("slow");
  });
/*  
  $("button").click(function(){
    var theID = $(this).attr('id');  
    $("#"+theID).slideDown("slow");
    $("td.#"+theID).slideDown("slow");
  });
  */
});
</script>
```

**The table query**

```
$query = "select * from $table_select";
$result = mysql_query($query);

echo "<table id = 'table-1'>";

$num_columns = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<tr>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) 
    {
        echo "<th id='".$i."'>";
        $meta = mysql_field_name($result, $i);
        if($i == 0) {
            $arg1 = $meta;
        }
        $field_name[] = $meta;
        echo "$meta</th>";
    }
$k = 0;
while($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $v[] = $table[0];
    echo "<tr class = 'hid_tr'>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
        echo "<td id='".$field_name[$i]."'>{$table[$i]}</td>";
        if($i == $num_columns-1) {
            echo '<td><form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="post"> <input type="hidden" id="quoteid" name="quoteid" value='.$v[$k].' /><input type="hidden" id="db" name="db" value='.$db_select.' /> <input type="hidden" id="table" name="t" value='.$table_select.' /> <input type="hidden" id="field" name="field" value='.$arg1.' /> <input type="submit" name="formDelete" id"formDelete" value="" style="background-color:#f00;color:#fff;"/></form></td>';
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    $k += 1; 
}
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
        //echo '<a href="" id="'.$field_name[$i].'">Slide up</a>';
        echo '<td><button id="'.$field_name[$i].'">Toggle '.$field_name[$i].'</button></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    /*
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
        //echo '<a href="" id="'.$field_name[$i].'">Slide Down</a>';
        echo '<td><button id="'.$field_name[$i].'">Slide down</button></td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    */

echo "</table>";
```

**The toggle button**

```
echo '<tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
    //echo '<a href="" id="'.$field_name[$i].'">Slide up</a>';
    echo '<td><button id="'.$field_name[$i].'">Toggle '.$field_name[$i].'</button></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: For the table query, shouldn't there be an `echo "<\tr>";` too?

Comment: Edited the question, there's an `echo "</tr>"` in the code

Comment: Is it possible to post a sample of the html that gets generated? Only the part that matters please

Comment: Here you go [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kdn34zvn8sw3xmk/sample.png?dl=0) dropbox link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is you want all the rows' 3rd tds to be hidden when someone clicks the button in the 3rd td of the top row, then you need to do something like this:

CREATING THE HEADERS

```
echo '<tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
    //The button calls a function with the proper position
    echo '<td id="hideableHeader' . $i . '"><button onclick="hide(' . $i . ');">Toggle '.$field_name[$i].' </button></td>';
}
echo '</tr>';
```

CREATING THE COLUMNS WITH DATA

Here, you give each TD an id that combines its row and column index like this:

```
'<td id="hideable_' . $rowNum . '_' . $colNum . '">datahere</td>';
```

And keep track of total rows.

HIDING (this is a javascript function)

```
function hide(colNum)
{
    //This is the header which will store its state for toggling
    var header = document.getElementById( "hideableHeader" + colNum );

    //Hide all of these tds starting after the first header row
    for ( var row = 0; row < totalRows; row++ )
    {
        for ( var col = 0; col < totalCols; col++ )
        {
            var column = document.getElementById( "hideable_" + row + "_" + col );

            //Is hidden, show it
            if ( header.isHidden === true ) column.style.visibility = "visible";

            //Hide it
            else column.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
}
```